# how to set and retrive localstorage object on certain conditions

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

I am working on a dice game and i have a timer which is calculating total time taken to win the game. So i want to store that total time taken in localstorage and display later on the screen. Basically i want to store it in the local storage only if the time taken is less than previous time record(which i haven't worked on yet as i am struggling to set and get that local storage properly). I am facing issues while showing time taken on the UI which i am fetching from the localstorage.

Below is the code where i have initialized a state "const [recordTime, setRecordtime]" which is supposed to hold previous time taken value from local storage. Also localstorage which i am fetching is also getting run multiple times as shown in the below screenshot in the console output.

```
const [recordTime, setRecordtime] = useState(fetchPrevioustime())

function fetchPrevioustime(){
        const recordedTime = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(("recordTime")))
        console.log(recordedTime)
        //const recordedTimesc = localStorage.getItem(("recordTimesc"))
       if(recordedTime !== null){
            return{
                recordedTime
            }
        } 
    }
```

I have a useEffect which gets triggered when game is won(tenzies is holding won state below in my code) and sets the localstorage to current time taken and also sets above "recordTime" state.

```
useEffect(() => {
            if(tenzies){
               let temp1 = [{
                mn: mn,
                sc: sc
            }]
            localStorage.setItem("recordTime", JSON.stringify(temp1))
            setRecordtime(temp1)
        }    
    },[tenzies]
    )
```

Below are the constants where mn and sc are getting calculated and i am using these constant in above effect.

```
const mn = ("0" + Math.floor((timer / 60000) % 60)).slice(-2)
const sc = ("0" + Math.floor((timer / 1000) % 60)).slice(-2)
const mlsc = ("0" + ((timer / 10) % 100)).slice(-2)
```

Inside my return of function component i am displaying recordTime.sc to show the time taken. But this is currently showing as blank on the UI.

```
return (
        <main>
            <h1 className="title">Tenzies</h1> 
            <p className="instructions">Roll until all dice are the same. Click each die to freeze it at its current value between rolls.</p>
            <div className= "congrats" style={stylesWon}>Congrats! You have won the game. <br></br>
            You took {mn > 0 && `${mn}minutes and ` } {sc}  seconds.
           Your best time is {recordTime.sc}
            </div>
            <div className="display" style={stylesTimer}>
                <span>{mn}:</span>
                <span>{sc}:</span>
                <span>{mlsc}</span>
            </div><br></br>
            <div className="dice-container">
                {diceElements}
            </div>
            {/*<button className="roll-dice" onClick={rollDice}>{tenzies ? "New Game" : "Roll"}</button>*/}
            <button className="roll-dice" onClick={rollDice}>{buttonText()}</button>
            {tenzies && <Confetti />}
            
        </main>
    )
}
```

Below is the output screen -
[image]

hoping to get some clarity about where i am doing things wrong.

Comment: Can you please reproduce your project by forking this [Codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-cannon-o9xjpg) and past the link? I'm having hard picturing it, maybe others too.

Comment: @yousoumar here is my stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/github/nikjd-git/reactProjects/tree/master3tenzie

Answer (score 0):

You need to curry the function to use as initialiser for useState:
See [Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state)
This should work:

```
const [recordTime, setRecordtime] = useState(() => fetchPrevioustime());
```

You could also use an effect like this.

```
useEffect(() => {
       setRecordTime(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("recordTime")))  
})
```

Once the component mounts, and renders, this effect will run, then read and set the recordtime state prop.

If you were going to use a store like redux for example, this would also typically where you would dispatch the action to initialise state for the component.  I would also tend to move things like read from LS to the actions/sagas - but that's a bit out of scope for the question.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but time value is still coming as blank on the screen.